# Passing textfield text data but receiving nil

Tags: ios, swift

I've made a project and run across and error. I have a view that pops up which contains a text field. My goal is someone enters their name into the text field, and it calculates the length of the string, makes sure its long enough, and creates an instance from that. However, when i run this, whenever i click the button, it crashes saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, even though there are no errors in my code. Please help thanks. The error is in the function `confName` on the line that starts with if `countElements`()

```
import UIKit
class PlayScreen : UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var scroller: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var PlayView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scroller.contentSize.height = PlayView.frame.height
    scroller.contentSize.width = PlayView.frame.width
    scroller.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

var tutView1 : UIView!
var tutView1TextField : UITextField!
var tutView1Label : UILabel!
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    var yPos = (PlayView.frame.height/8)
    var xPos = (PlayView.frame.width/8)
    tutView1 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 10, 10))
    tutView1.backgroundColor=UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    tutView1.layer.cornerRadius=25
    tutView1.layer.borderWidth=2
    tutView1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    self.view.addSubview(tutView1)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.25, animations: {
        self.tutView1.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 10+((xPos*6)-10), height: 10+((yPos*6)-10))
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            var tutView1Label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((self.tutView1.frame.width/8), (self.tutView1.frame.height/8), ((self.tutView1.frame.width/8)*6), ((self.tutView1.frame.height/4))))
            tutView1Label.text = "Welcome to your city mayor! Please give us your name and let your term begin!"
            tutView1Label.numberOfLines = 2
            tutView1Label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment(rawValue: 1)!
            tutView1Label.font = UIFont(name: tutView1Label.font.fontName, size: 20)
            self.tutView1.addSubview(tutView1Label)
            var tutView1TextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(self.tutView1.frame.width/2, self.tutView1.frame.height/2, self.tutView1.frame.width/3, self.tutView1.frame.height/10))
            tutView1TextField.frame.origin.x -= tutView1TextField.frame.width/2
            tutView1TextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            tutView1TextField.placeholder = "Name"
            tutView1TextField.layer.cornerRadius=12
            tutView1TextField.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            tutView1TextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment(rawValue: 1)!
            tutView1TextField.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            self.tutView1.addSubview(tutView1TextField)

            var tutView1Button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(self.tutView1.frame.width/2, (self.tutView1.frame.height/4)*3, self.tutView1.frame.width/4, self.tutView1.frame.height/12))
            tutView1Button.frame.origin.x -= tutView1Button.frame.width/2
            tutView1Button.setTitle("Start your rule!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            tutView1Button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            tutView1Button.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            tutView1Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
            tutView1Button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: tutView1Label.font.fontName, size: 13)
            tutView1Button.addTarget(self, action: "confName:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
            self.tutView1.addSubview(tutView1Button)
    })
}

func confName(sender: UIButton!) {
    if countElements(tutView1TextField.text) >= 3 && countElements(tutView1TextField.text) <= 12 {
        var playerIns = PlayerData(name: tutView1TextField.text)
    } else {
        tutView1Label.text = "Name must be between 3 and 12 characters!"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a property called tutView1TextField, but in animateWithDuration's completion block you are assigning the text field you create to a local variable of the same name,

```
 var tutView1TextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(self.tutView1.frame.width/2, self.tutView1.frame.height/2, self.tutView1.frame.width/3, self.tutView1.fravarme.height/10))
```

You should delete "var" there so you are assigning the new text field to your property, not the local variable.

You also have the same problem with tutView1Label.